# How to return output of a firebase function to the global variable of index.js file

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm making a firebase function file containing the following global variable and constant:

```
const cloudRegion = 'asia-east1';
var deviceId = 'esp32_25CA4C';
...
```

I'm also trying to make a firebase function to swap the 'deviceID' variable to another value. this firebase function is an HTTPSCallable function that is called when I submit a form, the content of the form will be used to change the global variable

see below the code of the function itself:

```
exports.insertDevice = functions.https.onCall((data, context) =>{
  deviceID = data.text;
  return
});
```

the function ran without any error but I'm not quite sure if the global vaiable actually changed.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try this way, make deviceId as const and run your code. If your code is throwing error saying const cannot be changes then it can be confirmed that your deviceId is being accessed inside the function. Then revert back your const change.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, if your function lives in the same instance of the Cloud Function that has the variables and the scope of the variable is global, you will have access to it.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations):

> If you declare a variable in global scope, its value can be reused in subsequent invocations without having to be recomputed.

In other words a global variable will have instance-wide scope.